# How to show standard output in TUI?

Tags: rust, stdout, tui

Let's assume we already have a project where there is a main crate which depends on many other crates (some from `crates.io` and some other local).

And now I want to add a [Terminal User Interface](https://docs.rs/tui/latest/tui/) to it, with one of the widgets showing what up to now it was being shown in the terminal via standard output.

So I actually have 2 questions:

1. How do I capture std output to show it in a TUI widget?
2. How do I organize this? Do I run as new main crate TUI and add as a dependency the previous main (this might be a problem for the project)? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole architecture you're going to need, but here's what I would try:

(note: I'm relatively new in both Rust *and* TUI in Rust)

#### Output

The command output is often printed via stdout. If you use Rust's Command then you probably do (this is pseudo code):

```
let mut cmd = std::process::Command::new("....");
cmd.status().expect("Something went wrong");
```

To capture the stdout (and stream from it) you can [see this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511615/how-to-pass-real-time-stdout-line-of-a-shell-command-to-function-in-rust), which will show you how to use `Piped()` so you can use a `BufReader` to read the output. From there you will need to pass this to your UI.

If you're using TUI-RS, you would probably benefit from looking at various [examples on their repo](https://github.com/fdehau/tui-rs/tree/v0.19.0/examples) where they set up the basic arch to communicate from a *thread* back to the UI using a mpsc (multi-producer, single consumer) channel.

When learning about this (I ultimately went with [Cursive](https://docs.rs/cursive/latest/cursive/index.html#) as it was better suited for my "kind of app" at the time), I found [this github repository](https://github.com/zupzup/rust-commandline-example) of a Rust Command-Line example using TUI of great help to put the pieces together. I also learned a lot from [this](https://monkeypatch.io/blog/2021/2021-05-31-rust-tui/) *simplified* version of the [Spotify TUI](https://github.com/Rigellute/spotify-tui) App's architecture.

You're going to have to send the output of your terminal (stdout/err) via the channel to the receiver end who has means to talk to the UI (likely by delivering events) which will ultimately "print" the commands in your "widgets".